# How can I animate twitching movement with code?

Tags: animation, three.js

I created an animation to illustrate what I'd like to achieve with code: [Example of twitches](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjhBB.gif)

It stays still and occasionally rotates quickly, then returns to its original state.

Would be great to be able to turn it up upon hovering for example, to make it shake violently for 1 sec. But that's less important.

Comment: Just use [`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) to update the rotation on each frame.

Comment: @Marquizzo, I just posted a more detailed answer, based off of `Math.random()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building upon Marquizzo's answer:

> Just use [`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) to update the rotation on each frame.

Using [`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) on its own, won't achieve this effect. If you want it to stay around one place, like shown in your GIF, you can do it like so:

```js
function getRandomDecimal(min, max) {  //Generates the rotation value
    var rand = Math.random()*(max-min) + min;
    var power = Math.pow(10, 2);
    return Math.floor(rand*power) / power;
}

function render(){
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    requestAnimationFrame(render);

    objectToTwitch.rotation.x = getRandomDecimal(-1, 1); //Set the x rotation to a random decimal from `-1` to `1`.
};

render(); //Calling the function manually the first time
```

Let me explain this code. We start with a custom function called `getRandomDecimal()`, which takes the parameters of `min` and `max`. We then set the rotation of you object to a random number between `-1`, `min`, and `1`, `max`. This changes 60 times a second, or the user's browser's frame rate. If this "twitch" effect happens too fast, you can fire the line of code somewhere else in your program.

That should do it~

Comment: Indeed that looks solid! Thank you. Do you have any suggestions on an efficient way of firing it off in intervals? SetTimeOut() maybe?

Comment: `rotation.set()` expects 3 values, not just one.

Comment: @Marquizzo, Whoops! Fixed that

Comment: @AlexM, since you're looking for a hover effect, I would look into raycasters. Once you detect that the object is being hovered on, you could fire the code in a `setTimeout`, like you said.

Comment: @Anye So close, but not quite there yet... it should be `object.rotation.x = getRandomDecimal();` because [Euler.x is a property, not a method](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=Group#api/en/math/Euler.x)

Comment: Wow, I can't believe i missed that. That's why I'm still a student :)